# Laravel .env configuration works with Laravel 5.2 but gives 2002 error with Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

2 working fine I set up the .env file like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=phonelist
DB_USERNAME=phonelist
DB_PASSWORD=*****
```

Now I cloned from github a project developed in Laravel 5.1 and I created a .env file with the same host and port just created a new db with new user.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=pinboard
DB_USERNAME=pinboard
DB_PASSWORD=test
```

I just keep getting

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I can see the errors include the values from my .env file. Anything else I can do to troubleshoot this?  Like I said 5.2 connects fine, I can make migrations and all but 5.1 throws the error.  I am positively certain that DB, USER, and PASS as typed correctly.

Comment: Could you show config file (database.php)

Comment: 'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],

Comment: THere can be problem with your port configuration. You maybe try add it to host: `127.0.0.1:8889`

Comment: Hi Flip thats the thing this same port and ip configuration works fine in 5.2

Comment: Just I just changed my .env file to an empty port and 127.0.0.1:8889, and it did not work still SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused